# Error When Querying Database with Geometry Type Using Entity Framework Core and Npgsql

Tags: .net, database, npgsql

I'm encountering an issue while querying a PostgreSQL database with Entity Framework Core and Npgsql, where the database contains a column of type **`geometry`**. I want to map this **`geometry`** type to a C# **`Geometry`** object in my DTO class, but I'm receiving a casting error. Here are the details of my setup:

```
using Domain.Entities;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PolylineDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Layer { get; set; }
    public List<VertexDto> Vertexes { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public int PolylineId { get; set; } // Foreign Key
    public Geometry? Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

**Querying the Database:**

I'm querying the database using the following method:

```
public async Task<List<PolylineDto>> GetAllPolylinesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Use EF Core to query the polylines from your database
    return await _context.Polylines.ProjectToDto().ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

**Error Received:**

When calling the GET endpoint, I'm encountering the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type public.geometry to Byte[]
   at Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandling.NpgsqlTypeHandler.ReadCustom[TAny](NpgsqlReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method451(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Application.Services.ObjectEvidentationRepository.GetAllPolylinesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\josip\git\firmadva\GeoAppPortal_BE\src\Application\Services\ObjectEvidentationRepository.cs:line 24
   at WebAPI.Endpoints.Buildings.GetAll.GetAllObjectsEndpoint.HandleAsync(CancellationToken ct) in C:\Users\josip\git\firmadva\GeoAppPortal_BE\src\WebAPI\Endpoints\Polylines\GetAll\GetAllObjectsEndpoint.cs:line 18
   at FastEndpoints.Endpoint`2.ExecAsync(CancellationToken ct)
   at FastEndpoints.Endpoint`2.ExecAsync(CancellationToken ct)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.SwaggerUiIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.RedirectToIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What steps should I take to resolve this casting issue and correctly map the **`geometry`** column to the **`Geometry`** property in my DTO class for my GET endpoint to work? If any aditional data is needed just ask.

Comment: What is `ProjectToDto` ? EF Core doesn't have such a method. What does it do? Are you automatically generate the Select expression, or map the resulting object to another one?

Comment: It looks like `ProjectToDto` is a Mapperly mapping method. Whats the definition of it? Of what type is the `Geometry` property in the entity?